# Prove that x_n tends to 0 (real-analysis)

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $(x_n)$ is a sequence of positive terms and that the sequence $y_n$=$(x_{n+1})/(x_n)$ converges to a limit L<1. Prove that the sequence x_n converges to 0

I'm not sure exactly how to start it but I know that if $x_n$ tends to 0 then $1/(x_n)$ tends to $infinity$. I know it can be solved doing two parts. 
The first part being induction and the second part is the squeeze theorem.

For example say $x_2 < Lx_1$ and then $x_3<Lx_2$. If say L=1/2 then L is monotone decreasing. I just don't know how to start the proof.

Comment: Check this out: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/697511/help-proving-exercise-on-sequences-in-bartles-elements

Comment: Before that check this out http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question

Comment: Are you sure is $(x_n+1)/x_n$ and not $x_{n+1}/x_n$?

Comment: Yes that's is what I meant I am sorry. It should be $x_{n+1}/x_n$

Answer (score 0):

$y_n =\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} \to L <1$ and all the $x_n \in \mathbb{R}^{>0}$ (non-zero). Then the serie $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x_n$ converges (by the the ratio test). So $x_n \to 0$.