# What does "for sufficiently large $n$" mean?

Tags: terminology, self-learning

> The question essentially is, In a general/common context what does
>   "for sufficiently large $n$" mean?

My initial grasp of the phrase went, "for **an** $n$ that is greater than a required bound". But I am not sure I've got it properly. For an example consider the following Theorem found in Bartle's Elements of Real Analysis:

> Suppose $X = (x_n)$ is a convergent sequence in $\Bbb R^p$ with limit
>   $x$. If there exists an element $c$ in $\Bbb R^p$ and a number $r \gt
>  0 $ such that $\left|{\left|{ x_n - c }\right|}\right| \le r$ for $n$
>   sufficiently large, then $\left|{\left|{ x - c }\right|}\right| \le r$

According to the proof of this theorem by sfficiently large $n$ the author means all natural numbers greater than a certain bound. The same phrase is also found in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/697511/help-proving-exercise-on-sequences-in-bartles-elements) and I think is used in the same way. But say in the application of a theorem similar to the one mentioned, how would you claim the condition is correct for "sufficiently large $n$"? Am a little confused. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "There is an $N$ such that for all $n \geqslant N$ ..."

Comment: @Daniel Fischer: And this is what it means in general?

Comment: @Ishfaaq Yes, that is all there is to it. It means that after some threshold the statement is true.

Comment: @Pedro Tamaroff: Alright.I guess that settles it. Thanks a lot guys..

Comment: I've also encountered

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}\Big[\Big\{A^{(n)}_\epsilon\Big\}\Big] &> 1- \epsilon & , \forall n > N_\epsilon
\end{align*}

where $\forall n > N_\epsilon$ just means "*for $n$ sufficiently large*".